Cannot resolve 'fs' in project directory/node_modules/electron
I am building a project with react js and electron combined. In that project I am getting this error. There are other solutions in stack overflow suggesting to make changes in webpack.config.js file to add fallback: {fs: false} however after making that change I am getting blank page in my react app. I need fs module in electron part to create directories. Please help me

This question is similar to: How to solve this error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also duplicate/same problem as this, and many other questions
